# Bootstrap 3 div collapse order

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to build a website. I have the following layout as pictured here:

[image: layout]

Which is coded like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12 main-content">
   <div class="col-md-2 sidebar-left">
       <!-- Left sidebar content here -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7 main-articles">
       <!-- Main articles go here -->
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3 sidebar-right">
       <!-- Right sidebar content here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

When viewing on a mobile / tabled the layout displays like this:

```
1st div - left sidebar (pictured in red)      
2nd div - main-articles (pictured in yellow)  
3rd div - right sidebar (pictured in greenish)
```

And I want it to display like this:

```
2nd div - main-articles (pictured in yellow)  
1st div - left sidebar (pictured in red)      
3rd div - right sidebar (pictured in greenish)
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Under your mobile media query, add floats to your divs like so..

```
#1st{
float:right;
}
#2nd{
float:left;
}
#3rd{
float:right;
}
```

This should get your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-push-2 main-articles">
       Main articles 
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-7 sidebar-left">
       Left sidebar
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar-right">
       Right sidebar 
   </div>
</div>`

See demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Debananda/y54kX/